# Find the value of dynamically generated buttons in a row

Tags: php, dynamic, html-table, submit

I have extracted hundreds of data from MYSQL database then populated them to a table. Each table has a column name "Preview" which will generate preview button. When we click on that preview button it has to pass Application ID of that row to genpdf.php but I could pass the Application ID of that specific row.

```
<form id="genpdf" action="genpdf.php" method="POST">                    
    <h3 style="padding:10px;">List of Application Submitted</h3>
    <table width="100%" style="padding: 10px;">             
        <tr>
            <td><strong>S. No.</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Application ID</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Date of Birth</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Telephone</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Email</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Preview</strong></td>       
        </tr>       
    <?php 
        $i = 1;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($record))
        {
            echo '<tr><td>' . $i . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['applicationid'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['title'] . ' ' . $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['middlename'] . ' ' . $row['familyname'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['dobmonth'] . '/' . $row['dobday'] . '/' . $row['dobyear'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['telephonet4'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['emailt4'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td><input type="submit" value "Preview" /></td>';
            $i += 1;
        }
    ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the form submit button with a regular link that calls the genpdf.php page and adds the applicationId as a HTTP GET parameter.

```
<a href="genpdf.php?applicationid=$row['applicationid']">Preview</a>
```

Comment: Its awesome. Spent 8 hours to figure it out but took 10 minute to get answer from this site.

Comment: If that was the aswer you were looking for and it solves your problem please accept it and mark it as solved (green check mark).